# React - useState not updating

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rq8etc?file=index.tsx)

Its a super simple sticky nav

When you scroll down the page the nav should show.

I'm using `window.pageYOffset` and checking when it goes over a number then setting useState then using that to show the nav

The console is outputting the `window.pageYOffset` but the useState doesn't get updated.

In the console the setState doesn't get updated

I can't see why

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [sticky, setSticky] = useState(false);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.pageYOffset;
    setSticky(position > 50 ? true : false);
    console.log("position = ", position);
    console.log("sticky = ", sticky);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div className="page">{sticky && <Nav />}</div>;
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: You could use `position: sticky` in your Nav to make it sticky, I reckon.

Comment: State is updated asynchronously. Use `useEffect` hook to log the updated value of `sticky`: `useEffect(() => { console.log(sticky); }, [sticky]);`

Comment: Why not just use CSS for it?

Comment: [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pxy58y?file=index.tsx)

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

setting `state` in react is an asynchronous operation and won't affect immediately, if you need to check the new changes you need to use the `useEffect` hook for that like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('sticky state is: ', sticky);
}, [sticky]);
```

this was for seeing that `sticky state` is changing and `Nav` component is showing but you can't see it. add this to your `Nav` Component so you can see it:

```
const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "fixed", top: 0, left: "300px" }}>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};
```

here is a working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qa44xu?file=index.tsx

Comment: You still didn't explain why the NAV component doesn't show

Comment: @DennisVash that's because the `Nav` Component is scrolled, and it's not visible at that moment. I've edited my answer to cover that too

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. The reason you can't see your nav even on scrolling down is because you haven't set the position of the Nav component as fixed. If you simply add the position: "fixed" property to the div, it works.

I've forked your code here. You can check it.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jgjhxb?file=style.css

And as @Taghi said, if you want to see it update, you need to use a useEffect because setState is asnchronous in React. I've added that to the code as well for you to check! :D Hope this helps